# Use Little Fermat Theorem to prove $341$ is not a prime base $7$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

This is how I thought about this question: first, assume $341$ is a prime then by the Little Fermat Theorem, I can get $7^{340}\equiv 1 \pmod {341}$. Then I have no idea how to continue. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: $7^{340} = 7\cdot (7^3) ^{113}$.

Comment: As a further hint consider $7^3,\,7^{30},\,7^{330}$.

Comment: Further hint: $341= 31\cdot 11$ and $7^{340}=7\cdot (7^{30})^{11}=7\cdot (7^{11})^{30}$.

Comment: @Maczinga Using the factorization of $341$ is cheating when trying to prove $341$ is not prime by a different method.

Comment: @BillDubuque Oups! I read the question the other way round ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your next step is to calculate $7^{340} \bmod 341$ and see if it actually is $1$.

In lieu of any clever observations, [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) provides a reasonably quick method. Using the binary representation of $340$ ($101010100$) to guide the steps, we want:

$$7^{340} = (\!(\!(\!(\!(\!(\!(7^2)^2\cdot 7)^2)^2\cdot 7)^2)^2\cdot 7)^2)^2$$

taking the result $\bmod 341$ at each step. This gives  $7^{340} \equiv 56 \bmod 341$, showing that $341$ is not prime.