# Fermat’s Little Theorem can be used to prove a given number is not prime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Present an argument using Fermat’s Little Theorem to show that $341$ is not a prime number.

How do we go about this? Would $a=7$ work?

Comment: What would $7^{340}$ have to be if $341$ were prime? Is it that?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167609/use-little-fermat-theorem-to-prove-341-is-not-a-prime-base-7

Comment: Why not try $a=3$ first?  Have you tried $a=2$ already?

Comment: @EthanBolker Is it 56? I used python to calculate the value((7**340)%341).

Comment: @EthanBolker Basically $7^{340} \mod{341}$.

Comment: Yes, it's $56$. Figure out what that tells you. I hope you are allowed to use Python on tomorrow's exam. I'm afraid I can't help you any more tonight.

Comment: @EthanBolker They obviously will not ask for such large computations.

Comment: @YFP Oftentimes computations of this apparent size can be with paper and pencil. You don't ever need to compute $7^{340}$ For instance, $7^3 = 343.$ That helps, right?

Comment: You could argue that $32^2\equiv 1 \bmod 341$ disproves primality by strong association with Fermat's little theorem. Kinda.

Comment: @Joffan You don't need Fermat if you know that. But how would you discover that without knowing the factorization of $341?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque The hard way, by looking at a few multiples of 341 and recognizing a square -1.

Comment: @Joffan That's not little Fermat but, rather, essentially [Fermat's Difference of Squares Factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_factorization_method) (with small multiplier, here $3)$

Answer (score 2):

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime number and $a$ is any natural number not divisible by $p$, then

$$ a^{p−1} \equiv 1\pmod{p} $$

Assuming $p = 341$ to be prime, we find this is not the case as

$$ 7^{341-1}=7^{340} \equiv 56 \pmod{341} $$

Hence, 341 is not a prime.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a proof using Fermat's *other* theorem, namely that primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$ are expressible as the sum of two squares, one of which is even and the other odd.

Since $341\equiv5$ mod $8$, the even square must be congruent to $4$ mod $8$ (odd squares being congruent to $1$ mod $8$).  This leaves only a handful of possibilities.  But

$$\begin{align}
341-2^2&=337\\
341-6^2&=305\\
341-10^2&=241\\
341-14^2&=145\\
341-18^2&=17
\end{align}$$

are all non-squares.  So $341$ cannot be prime.