# Fermat Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem I am trying to solve is how to use Fermat Little theorem to prove that the number 66013 is not prime. I found this problem on another website (Question Cove). The student who had to solve this problem didn't know how to proceed. I offered to help. I read the following lecture notes [Princeton lecture notes on cryptography](http://web.math.princeton.edu/math_alive/1/Notes2.pdf) and thought I would follow the same procedure. I wrote
$66013 = 257^2 + 36 = 256^2 + 513 + 36 = 2^{16} + 2^9 + 37$ but I am stuck after that. What is the correct approach?

Comment: How do you know your number $999\dots9$ is not a multiple of 66213?

Comment: Because the only way to get 999...9 is by multiplying 9 by 111...1?

Comment: $37*27 = 999$ so... that's not true.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169499/fermat-s-little-theorem-can-be-used-to-prove-a-given-number-is-not-prime).

Comment: It's a correct approach but not a very efficient  method.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I see this now. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fermat’s little theorem can be used to prove a given number is not prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169499/fermat-s-little-theorem-can-be-used-to-prove-a-given-number-is-not-prime)

Comment: Sorry about all the trouble. And thank you for the answers. I know now how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's little theorem is an incredibly inefficient method for proving primality. In this case the standard test for divisibility by 3 (by adding the digits and checking whether the sum is a multiple of 3) shows that $66213$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: 66213 = 9* 7357

Comment: Yes, indeed the quotient is easy to find. I was just pointing out that 66213 falls to the very simplest rule of thumb for checking primality.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $a:=3$.  We have
$$a^{66212}=3^{66212}\not\equiv1\pmod{66213}$$
because $3\mid 66213$.  Well, there, I used Fermat's Little Theorem!

**Edit:**  Originally, the OP's question was to disprove the primality of $66213$.

---

For the corrected question (with number $66013$), choose $a:=15781$.  Then,
$$a^2=249039961\equiv 38925\pmod{66013}\,.$$
That is,
$$a^4\equiv 38925^2=1515155625\equiv25249\pmod{66013}\,.$$
Finally,
$$a^5=a\cdot a^4\equiv 15781\cdot 25249=398454469\equiv 1\pmod{66013}\,.$$
That is,
$$a^{66013-1}=a^2\,\left(a^5\right)^{13202} \equiv a^2\cdot 1^{13202}\equiv a^2\equiv 38925\pmod{66013}\,.$$
Thus, $66013$ is not prime.

Comment: The base $a$ should be relatively prime.

Comment: But $\gcd(3,66213)\ne 1$ so no you did not use FLT.

Comment: If $66213$ were prime, any $a$ between $1$ to $66212$ could be used.  The point is, because $a=3$ couldn't be used, $66213$ is not prime.

Comment: @AnuragA Not "should".... "must".

Comment: But you can't claim $3|66213$ unless you know that $66213$ is not prime in the first place.  This argument is circular.

Comment: @fleablood I was trying to advise as opposed to enforce :-)

Comment: No, I didn't have to use circular logic to verify that $3\mid 66213$.  I can just divide it.  This problem is a joke.

Comment: I agree with Batominovski, it is a form of torture to set students tasks like this. And to placate Anurag A and fleablood, we are entitled to assume for a contradiction that $a = 3$ and $66213$ are relatively prime (since if they aren't then the prime $3$ divides $66213$).

Comment: But if you divide it then you have proving it is not prime.  You did not use FLT to prove it was prime.  You can't claim FLT proves it is not prime if you need to know it is not prime in order to use FLT.  Definitely circular.

Comment: I did use it.  It's jut not needed in my proof.  The question didn't say that FLT was the necessary ingredient.

Comment: Well, I don't disagree that it isn't torture.... but that's not a proof using FLT.  It's a proof that when it is done waves at FLT that just happens to be standing by the road.

Comment: You can't deny I didn't use FLT.

Comment: @fleablood: see my edited comment: I think Batominovski's appeal to Fermat's little theorem is quite justifiable.

Comment: "I did use it. It's jut not needed in my proof. The question didn't say that FLT was the necessary ingredient."  Okay.  That's a good joke and one I can approve of.  But... For the students (and overly serious posters like me) maybe it should be pointed out that it was a joke.  (Perhaps I should have realized from the beginning you were joking.)

Comment: @fleablood  Not all problems should be treated seriously.  This one certainly came out of an absent-minded person (I'm not pointing my finger at the OP, but the one who created the question).

Comment: "You can't deny I didn't use FLT."  Oh, you have no idea what I'm capable of denying!

Comment: Well, prove that I didn't use FLT.

Comment: Alright, this is a dopey question as $3|66213$ is pretty obvious.   Asking how to use FLT to show a number isn't prime seems a fair and legitimate question, doesn't it?  I mean the point of these excercises isn't to get the right answer (who *cares* if 66213 is prime?  My sushi will still cost the same) but to demonstrate concepts.

Comment: Sure, you can use FLT in a more sensible setting.  This problem is obviously designed to be stupid, due to the large number $66213$ with a pretty obvious divisor $3$.  If it were to give a good practice, like the link given by Dietrich Burde above, then I wouldn't have much objection.  The number $341$ is small and sensible to be tested.

Comment: @Batominovski  May I ask how you picked  a:=15781.?

Comment: WolframAlpha did it.  I searched for the smallest integer $a>0$ such that $a^5\equiv1\pmod{66013}$.  If you want to use a smaller number, then be my guest.  This problem is about brute force anyhow.